# MuiCallout component in mui 5

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to create component similar to muicallout examples that they use their website mui 5. but the component is not listed in componets list in.

```
<aside class="MuiCallout-root MuiCallout-warning"><p>This API is at an unstable stage and is subject to change in the future.</p>

</aside>
```

This is the html code that I copied from mui page.
Alert component is similar to muicallout. but the problem is how to add outlined border with variant "standard". in callout component, it has light background color and border also.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can't help you with the callout component. However, if all you want is an Alert with a border in a matching color, you can fix that like so:

```
<Alert
  icon={false}
  severity="info"
  sx={{ border: `1px solid ${theme.palette.info.main}` }}
>
  Some content
</Alert>
```

The theme variable can be obtained with `const theme = useTheme()`, where useTheme is imported with `import { useTheme } from '@mui/material/styles'`